# Concern with overtightening brass shower valve fitting

Tags: shower, leak, pex, brass-fitting

I installed a shower valve with 4 brass 1/2" male fittings. Before installing I wrapped each thread with teflon 4 or 5 times. I installed it into 3x brass fittings that lead to PEX, and the 4th one I capped.

I hand-tightened all of the fittings and used my 12" wrench to wrench-tightened them a few turns each until they felt snug enough.

Initially, I had 1 slow drip leak on one inlet, and none on the others. So I tried redoing it a couple of times and had the same issue. I tried giving the problem inlet a few extra wraps of teflon, and wrench tightened until I couldn't tighten it anymore. That seemed to do the trick. However, the other three started leaking at that point, so I redid all of them and wrench-tightened them until I couldn't anymore. There are still a 2 or 3 threads exposed on each of the fittings. I marked up the brass female NPT fittings pretty badly on the outside. Its been a week now, and I've also run the valve for over an hour, and there haven't been any leaks.

At this point should I have any concerns about the possibility that I overtightened these fittings over the long term? I know that brass can deform with strain.

Thanks.

Comment: it is possible to over tighten, no way for us to know. Normally you would tighten by hand as far it goes, then add 1/4 to 1/2 turn with wrench

Comment: "A few turns each" beyond finger tight? Jeezy Creezy. Hopefully you mean "a few 1/6 turns each." I've joked that adjustable wrenches with full length handles should be a privilege earned by ironworkers when they finish their apprenticeships (apprentices tend to damage torch gauges by over-torquing them). You're a menace with that 12" wrench.